# keyboard event

Tags: java

i have added keyboard events....with robot class' object to write the key values on the notepad.....but as i press **"a"** it will interpret it as **"1"** and as so on...for all the keys...

when i m displaying the asci values for all the keys it will print accurate values like a-97,b-98 and so on....

why this  happened please give some solution....

Answer (score 2):

The [`Robot.keyPress`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#keyPress(int)) method takes in an `int` key code -- not an actual character code.

From the documentation regarding `keycode`:

```
keycode - Key to press (e.g. KeyEvent.VK_A)
```

Therefore, entering the following will not work:

```
Robot r = new Robot();
r.keyPress('a');            // Won't work -- it will press an "1"
```

To work correctly, one would have to use the constants from [`KeyEvent`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html):

```
Robot r = new Robot();
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);  // This works -- it will press an "a"
```

Also, if one wants to use the `KeyEvent`s returned from a `KeyListener`'s events such as `keyPressed` and `keyReleased`, the `KeyEvent` object has a [`getKeyCode`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#getKeyCode()) method which will return the `keycode` of the event.